# Is there a way to search for the viewport [(x,y)(x,y)] bounding a region in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, polygon

I am looking for a way where I can draw a bounding box for an entity through the screen coordinates that I have for that entity zoomed-in

**My objective is to:**

- Draw a rectangular box using the zoomed-in coordinates around that entity

**What I have:**

- For a particular geospatial entity, I have the coordinates "a" and "d" of the box "abcd" in the format [(lat,long)(lat,long)]
- The point coordinate for the entity (x,y)

Although I need to identify extent for that locality and draw a polygon accordingly, which I am not sure how to. I will make do with the zoomed-in box for now

PS. I am very new to QGIS and using it as a beginner just to achieve an objective, I might need to understand some of the requirements so any directions will help as well

Comment: Are you zooming in on features, or on random places without geometries?

Comment: I am zooming on places for which I have point coordinates

Comment: I am fetching entity point coordinates from a postgres database, which points to a the entity. Around which I need to draw the box surrounding it with my box coordinates

Comment: Oh sorry I must have clarified, by entity I meant an object on the map eg building, locality for which I wanted to draw a bounding box around @BERA

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data you have? And an example of what you want to create

Comment: I have a base map, which has all localities loaded up as points, for each of those points I have an external source of information which is a coordinate for a screen size zoomed in box to only fit that locality plus whatever extras are on the edges (because its a rectangle and a locality migh not necessarily be)

Comment: Sorry about the screenshot, I cannot show the data or the locations on the map, hope you understand